# how to listener event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

everyone,i am a beginner about js,so i have a Question,code:

```
var formDate=$("#formStudentInfo").serializeArray();
    var inputArray=[];

     for (var i=0;i<formDate.length;i++) {

        var element=$('#form_'+formDate[i]['name']);
        inputArray.push(element);
        console.log(inputArray)
        inputArray[i].on('click',function(){
            console.log(inputArray[0]['name']);
        })
     }
```

i have a form name is #formStudentInfo,there are two input in this form,input name is "form_name"and"form_userName",How do I get the input name，when i click input？ thanks everyone

Comment: Make a fiddle please

Comment: i remember as3 do it is "buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);" ,how to do in js?

Comment: Use 'onclick' event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp in html `<element onclick="myScript">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the looping counter variable inside the asynchronous callback handler.

Value of `i` will not be same when the element is clicked. since by that time it will always be equal to `formDate.length` since when the element is clicked this loop has already run.

Replace

```
inputArray[i].on('click',function(){
    console.log(inputArray[0]['name']);
})
```

with

```
element.on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('name')); //using the reference to current element using $(this)
})
```

or simply

```
element.click(function(){ //directly using the click method rather than delegation
   console.log($(this).attr('name')); //using the reference to current element using $(this)
})
```